# Python: gensim: RuntimeError: you must first build vocabulary before training the model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I know that this question has been asked already, but I was still not able to find a solution for it.

I would like to use gensim's `word2vec` on a custom data set, but now I'm still figuring out in what format the dataset has to be. I had a look at [this post](http://streamhacker.com/2014/12/29/word2vec-nltk/) where the input is basically a list of lists (one big list containing other lists that are tokenized sentences from the NLTK Brown corpus). So I thought that this is the input format I have to use for the command `word2vec.Word2Vec()`. However, it won't work with my little test set and I don't understand why.

What I have tried:

**This worked**:

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
from nltk.corpus import brown
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

brown_vecs = word2vec.Word2Vec(brown.sents())
```

**This didn't work**:

```
sentences = [ "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs","yoyoyo you go home now to sleep"]
vocab = [s.encode('utf-8').split() for s in sentences]
voc_vec = word2vec.Word2Vec(vocab)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work with the "mock" data, even though it has the same data structure as the sentences from the Brown corpus:

**vocab**:

```
[['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dogs'], ['yoyoyo', 'you', 'go', 'home', 'now', 'to', 'sleep']]
```

**brown.sents()**: (the beginning of it)

```
[['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.'], ['The', 'jury', 'further', 'said', 'in', 'term-end', 'presentments', 'that', 'the', 'City', 'Executive', 'Committee', ',', 'which', 'had', 'over-all', 'charge', 'of', 'the', 'election', ',', '``', 'deserves', 'the', 'praise', 'and', 'thanks', 'of', 'the', 'City', 'of', 'Atlanta', "''", 'for', 'the', 'manner', 'in', 'which', 'the', 'election', 'was', 'conducted', '.'], ...]
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Default `min_count` in gensim's Word2Vec is set to 5. If there is no word in your vocab with frequency greater than 4, your vocab will be empty and hence the error. Try

```
voc_vec = word2vec.Word2Vec(vocab, min_count=1)
```

Comment: Also if your data comes from an iterator, makes sure it has not already been consumed.

Comment: +1

From documentation:
min_count: (default 5) The minimum count of words to consider when training the model; words with an occurrence less than this count will be ignored

Answer (score 5):

Input to the gensim's Word2Vec can be a list of sentences or list of words or list of list of sentences.

E.g.

```
1. sentences = ['I love ice-cream', 'he loves ice-cream', 'you love ice cream']
2. words = ['i','love','ice - cream', 'like', 'ice-cream']
3. sentences = [['i love ice-cream'], ['he loves ice-cream'], ['you love ice cream']]
```

**build the vocab before training**

```
model.build_vocab(sentences, update=False)
```

[just check out the link for detailed info](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)